# Перевести буквы из указанной строки в верхний регистр

Tags: c#, массивы, текст

Есть массив строк. Если у строки сверху и снизу пустая строка - необходимо сделать её капсом.
В чём проблема?

```
for (int i = 1; i < count-1; i++)
{                               
    if (a[i-1] == String.Empty && a[i+1] == String.Empty)
    {
        a[i] = a[i].ToUpper();
        counter2++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tГлав: {0} шт.", counter2);
```

upd: Текст, глава, текст, глава, текст. Данный код делает так: Текст, ГЛАВА, ТЕКСТ, ГЛАВА, текст.

Comment: В том, что в C# массивы индексируются от нуля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool isPrevCaption = true;   // true если статья начинается с текста, и false если с заглавия


 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
     {       
        if (a[i] == String.Empty) continue;

        if(!isPrevCaption ) {
            a[i] = a[i].ToUpper();
             isPrevCaption = true;
        } 
        else  isPrevCaption  = false; 



}
```

Comment: Допустим, но я по другому выкрутился. Проблема в том, что теперь так: Текст, ГЛАВА, ТЕКСТ, ГЛАВА, текст.

Comment: Сейчас на этом застопорился: https://goo.gl/ZgNeeZ

Comment: А как реализовать пропуск абзаца?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30318/discussion-between--and-ni55an).

Answer (score 0):

```
char a = 'A';
char b = a | 0b00100000; // a

char ret = a ^ 0b00100000; // A
```